# How to get bash to execute all commands in a file (cygwin)

Tags: bash, ssh, cygwin, x11

I have the following command:

```
xterm -display :4.0 -e /bin/bash -l /home/script.txt
```

Script.txt contains (sensitive stuff changed):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
ssh -XY user@255.255.255.0
program &
sleep 3s
```

Now when I run the above command in a windows CLI, it opens an xterm and connects via SSH, asking for a password. After I enter the password, it stops executing. I `set -x` to see what was being executed and it only executes up to the SSH connection then stops.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: The answer explains the behavior.  If you want information about how to get specific other behavior then you'll need to explain in detail exactly what you're trying to achieve, as that is not at all clear from the prose and code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you expect it to execute your `program &` on the ssh host, but if you call it like this the ssh does not know this and just opens you a session.

You can append the command to the ssh call like

```
ssh -XY user@255.255.255.0 'program &'
```

Not sure where you want the sleep to be, probably outside the ssh?

Comment: This will however terminate `program` as soon as it's started since the ssh session will end.

Comment: Hmm interesting point, what I see here is that the & background operator simply won't work at all - I was going to suggest to put the entire ssh in the background but then the password login described by OP won't work

Comment: You can use `nohup` to ignore `SIGHUP` send by ssh. This will let the command run until it ends, even if a ssh session is ended.

Comment: I can't reproduce it - for me it looks like it would simply ignore the `&` in the ssh, but the `nohup` clearly is the solution for that, I agree - I suggest we let OP give a try